# React 16 img dissapearing after rotate

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

If I rotate my image with CSS in react 16, the image disappears.

in fiddle the code works :

http://jsfiddle.net/dmofoxb3/

**steps to reproduce :**

( in powershell or cmd )

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
npm start
```

add a variation of the above code (I want it on click) :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../../../img/logo.png';
import menu from '../../../img/menu_icon.png';
import './TopBar.css';

class TopBar extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            firstMenuLevel: false,
        };
        this.toggleFirstMenuLevel = this.toggleFirstMenuLevel.bind(this);
    }

    toggleFirstMenuLevel(){
        this.setState({
            firstMenuLevel: !this.state.firstMenuLevel,
        });
        console.log(this.firstMenuLevel);
    }

    render() {
        const {firstMenuLevel} =  this.state;
        return (
            <div className="TopBar">
                <div><img src={logo} className="logo" alt="Company Logo" /></div>
                <h1 className="TopBar-title">App</h1>
                <div
                    className="menu-icon-container"
                    onClick={this.toggleFirstMenuLevel}
                >
                    <img
                        src={menu}
                        className={firstMenuLevel ? 'menu-icon spin' : 'menu-icon'}
                        alt="Menu Icon" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TopBar;
```

here is what I get :

[image: animation with img disappearing]

as you can see via the chrome developer tools the img is still there and has not moved offscreen it simply chooses not to load anymore while the spin class is added and the rotate transformation is finished.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to your img style (or just `backface-visibility: hidden;` but it seems to be only a chrome issue)

Comment: wow! well done! uhhh... why does this work? and why does this happen in the first place?

Comment: Browsers have sometime weird behaviours especially with css animations, this bug will maybe be fixed, maybe not !